# Intuitive, posibly graphical idea behind the convex conjugate of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I am reading about convex duality, i.e. given a function $f: X \to (- \infty, + \infty]$ you define

$$ f^* (x^*) = \sup_{x \in X} \{ \langle x^* , x \rangle - f(x) \}$$

with $X$, say, Banach and separable (take $\mathbb{R}^n $ not to complicate things) and $X^*$ its dual. Now, I admit convex analysis has been a topic I've been wanting to understand better for a long time, but I still haven't. Later on in the notes they prove the Fenchel-Moreau theorem which characterizes lower semicontinuous convex functions and also give other results, definitions etc. But my question is much simpler. And it is: how do tou "see" $f^*$ ? Is there a way? I want to have a really basic intuition of it, like the derivative that is the slope of a curve, the integral which is the area below the graph etc. After that I feel more confident to be able to manipulate it and think about it much much better. For example, is it posible to "see" graphically that $(f^*)^* =f$ if $f$ is convex and lower semicontinuous (maybe I am asking too much, but I'll give it a shot)

Comment: Check the books by Hiriarrt-Urruty and Lemarechal, you will find some nice illustrations, using homogenization cones.